# How to understand the stride size for parallel reduction when doing multiple add?

Tags: cuda, reduction

I am learning Mark Harris's implementation of Optimizing [Parallel Reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf).

I am confused by these several lines on page 32:

```
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + threadIdx.x;
unsigned int gridSize = blockSize*2*gridDim.x;
sdata[tid] = 0;
while (i < n){
sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize];
i += gridSize;}
__syncthreads();
```

Why here the grid stride is `gridSize = blockSize*2*gridDim.x;`? From my understanding, we should compute the grid one by one? So it should be `gridSize = blockSize*gridDim.x;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is very similar to the answer to your previous question.  Each thread in the block (or grid) handles two elements from the data set:

```
sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize]
              element 1     element 2
```

for every stride that the grid takes.  Therefore if we measure the grid stride in terms of the number of elements processed per stride, that number is twice the grid dimension in threads.

grid size in threads:

```
gridSize = blockSize*gridDim.x;
```

grid size in number of elements processed per stride:

```
gridSize = 2*blockSize*gridDim.x;
```

Comment: One more question, if without this optimization, the kernel is ```reduce<<<grid, block>>>```, after this optimization, the kernel size will be ```reduce<<<grid/2, block>>>```. Right?

Comment: This is not necessarily an optimization, and this is a grid-stride loop, so there is no required relationship between the grid size and the data set size.   Either will work.  You may wish to study how [grid-stride loops](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) work.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I could understand if the data set is very large, it is not necessary to reduce the grid size. Since SM is limited. But how if in some cases, the data set is very small, for example ```data_size=128``` and ```blockDim.x=64```, then we should use ```grid/2``` to save resouces?

Comment: Certainly the `grid` size need not be larger than half the dataset size for this case.

Comment: But in this [example](https://github.com/deeperlearning/professional-cuda-c-programming/blob/master/examples/chapter05/reduceInteger.cu#L239-L246), because the stride size is ```blockDim.x * 4```, so their kernel is  ```reduceGmemUnroll<<<grid.x / 4, block>>>```. That's why I'm wondering if I should reduce grid size to ```grid.x/2``` for the above example.

Comment: In your question, and up until this moment, I thought you were talking about a code in the material you linked in your question.  Now it seems you are asking about something else, from a different source.  I don't think it makes any sense to compare the two.  I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: Hi Robert, please take a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006140/how-to-determine-the-grid-size-when-doing-unrolling).

Comment: Hi @Robert Crovella could you please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006140/how-to-determine-the-grid-size-when-doing-unrolling)? Today I run the experiment and found that with a unrolling factor of 4, ```reduceGmemUnroll<<<grid.x / 4, block>>>```, the result is incorrect. It seems the book provide a wrong example, I have no idea how to configure the kernel size right now....

Comment: Btw, it seem it will only run the ```while``` loop for once. Because if we configure ```grid.x = ((size + block.x - 1) / block.x)```, then ```blockSize*gridDim.x``` is already the problem size...